# Is there a clever way to find a smaller number that produces the Euclidean algorithm of given length?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, euclidean-algorithm

Is there a simple way to tell if for a given $n$ there is $m$ such that the Euclidean algorithm on $n,m$ runs for a given number of steps, and/or a way to find $m$ efficiently (other than testing all $m<n$ by brute force)? For simplicity, restrict to $m$ relatively prime to $n$. For example, if $n=13$ and we want 1 step, then $m=6$ works: $13=2\cdot6+1$. And for 3 steps $m=7$ works: $13=1\cdot7+5$, $7=1\cdot5+2$, and $5=2\cdot2+1$.

Since the algorithm is used to find the modular inverse $m^{-1}$ (mod $n$) the fewer steps it takes the easier it is to find (so in particular few step runs are convenient for making homework problems ☺). Note that it is easy to find *pairs* for a given length of the algorithm. Since the continued fraction of $n/m=[q_0;q_1,\dots,q_k]$ records the quotients one can take an arbitrary continued fraction of given length, and find $n,m$ by contracting it. Hence an alternative way to ask the question is if there is an efficient way to “parametrize” all continued fractions with a given numerator.

If the general question is too hard, what can be said for $n$ prime, and/or small lengths like 2,3,4? It is easy for 1, since $n=q\cdot m+1$ the requisite $m$ are just the divisors of $n-1$. But already for 2 we have to find $m,r$ that simultaneously satisfy $m|(n-r)$ and $r|(m-1)$, which does not look obvious how to do.

Comment: The euclidean algorithm using integer division, or only subtraction?

Comment: @zyx I was counting divisions, but one can reformulate it in terms of subtractions I think.

Comment: For the subtraction version, representing the numbers as sums of Fibonacci numbers may be useful.    (F(n),F(n-1)) is the smallest pair that takes n steps to terminate.  Actually this is true for divisions also, as all quotients are 1 for that pair.

Comment: @zyx Interesting. Is there a way to "see" the length of Euclidean algorithm on $n,m$ given their Zeckendorf representations as Fibonacci sums?

Comment: Maybe to estimate it.  The quotient of F(m+n) by F(n) is (maybe with a shift of indices by 1) something like F(m) + F(m-n) + F(m-2n) + .... so potentially there is a good description using the Fibonacci  representation of m,n.

Comment: The length of the Euclidea algorithm applied to $(m,n)$ just depends on the length of the continued fraction of $\frac{m}{n}$.

Comment: I thought of this if $n<T_k$ then there are k-1 steps at most to reach the gcd. with any number ( other than 1 ?). Reasoning, is that if there were k unique differences the sum of these differences would equal the kth triangular number.  of course that's only an upper bound.

Answer (score 1):

As you have mentioned:

an alternative way to ask the question is if there is an efficient way to “parametrize” all continued fractions with a given numerator.

I think this result can be of some help to your question.
[image]

I am not sure how is it directly related to the question. Maybe some users can point out in the comments section.